# Save/updating problems in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, insert-update, laravel-5

I've been experimenting with Laravel - and I've run into a problem with saving/updating a record (a user's description). I've based the code off of some that works - so I'm kinda confused as to what I've messed up on.

I can make a change using php tinker (and it is reflected on the page - so it's not a database thing) - but when using the site itself, laravel isn't saving any of the text entered into the form.

These aren't the full files - just what I feel is probably relevant

Thank you! :)

P.S - It's silently failing, hence the frustration, and the need for a stack overflow post :)

---

**Form Element for changing description**

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['UserController@update', $user->id]]) !!}
    {!! Form::text('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

---

**UserController**

```
public function store(EditUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = new User($request->all());
    Auth::user()->users()->save($user);
    return redirect('home');
}

public function edit(User $user)
{
    // if owner is posts creator (collection id matches user id)
    if ($user->id == Auth::user()->id) {
        return view('home');
    } else {
        return redirect('home');
    }
}

public function update(User $user, EditUserRequest $request)
{
    // if owner is posts creator (collection id matches user id)
    if ($user->id == Auth::user()->id) {
        $user->update($request->all());
        return redirect('home');
    } else {
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

---

**EditRequestController**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class EditUserRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'description'    =>  'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

---

**dd($user)**

```
 User {#142 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "email"
    2 => "password"
  ]
  #hidden: array:2 [▼
    0 => "password"
    1 => "remember_token"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Oliver Williams"
    "email" => "Oliver.jack.williams@gmail.com"
    "description" => "lorem ipsum nonsense"
    "password" => "$2y$10$c65lDNJ0V8ibYT4QD6cnk.HmXPwBqlskHWzOzKi1vOlNKVR48y0iS"
    "remember_token" => "1e6Il0T1rjQQMKSAn09Gd8FLdh0CcYTs4Xd7B6IYUp02rNJ9IpSpV374kwRg"
    "created_at" => "2016-02-17 23:37:39"
    "updated_at" => "2016-02-18 00:48:44"
    "time" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Oliver Williams"
    "email" => "Oliver.jack.williams@gmail.com"
    "description" => "lorem ipsum nonsense"
    "password" => "$2y$10$c65lDNJ0V8ibYT4QD6cnk.HmXPwBqlskHWzOzKi1vOlNKVR48y0iS"
    "remember_token" => "1e6Il0T1rjQQMKSAn09Gd8FLdh0CcYTs4Xd7B6IYUp02rNJ9IpSpV374kwRg"
    "created_at" => "2016-02-17 23:37:39"
    "updated_at" => "2016-02-18 00:48:44"
    "time" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

---

**dd($user->update($request->all()));**

```
true
```

Comment: Can you `dd($user->update($request->all()))` and `dd($user)` ?

Comment: Added them to the bottom of the post - I hope I did it right - wasn't quite sure what I was looking at tbh :)

Comment: This means, `$user->update($request->all())` was successful. `dd($user)` shows the User object.

Comment: The description for the one I posted was the one I changed manually with php artisan tinker - on a 'normal' user, it just shows and empty string for the description "" - just incase that's a red herring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't apply to everyone - so I'm not sure if it qualifies as an answer - but I didn't add the new row to the 'fillable' array in 'User.php' - meaning it couldn't be mass assigned.

I'm a numpty. 
Thanks everyone :)